# Is the outer measure of $A\cup B$ equal to the sum of their outer measures if $A\cap B=\varnothing$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I understand that Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R$ is not countably additive. But if there are two disjoint sets, does the outer measure of their union equal the sum of their outer measure? Can someone give me a counterexample?

Comment: And I'm only considering subsets of the real numbers. I remember my professor said the answer is no. But I just can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_criterion

Answer (score 3):

Use transfinite induction to construct $2$ (or $2^{\aleph_0}$) disjoint subsets $A_i$ of the unit interval $[0,1]$, such that each $A_i$ has nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed subset of $[0,1]$. (These are called [Bernstein sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set).) Then each $A_i$ has outer measure $1$, as does the union of all the $A_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\Omega = \{a, b\}$. Define
$$
  \mu^*(A)
  =
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      0, & A = \emptyset
      \\
      1, & A \neq \emptyset
    \end{array}
  \right.
$$
This is an outer measure.

In this case,
$$
  \mu^*(\{a,b\}) = 1
  \neq
  2 = \mu^*(\{a\}) + \mu^*(\{b\}).
$$

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough. I'm only considering Lebesgue outer measure regarding subsets of real numbers. Do you have counterexamples on the real line?

Comment: @Badoe: Maybe you can try something like this... Consider the Lebesgue outer measure in $[0,1]$. Take a non measurable set $A$. Since it is non measurable, it's inner measure must not be equal its outer measure. But maybe it means that $\lambda^*(A) + \lambda^*(A^c) \neq 1$. I am not sure...

Comment: I guess you have to be more specific about what you admit as sets. There's a lot of riff-raff in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ that's really not worth considering, whereas if you admit docile (measurable) sets $E$ which satisfy $m_*(A) = m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$ you get disjoint additivity immediately. Your counter-example will require a choice, Mr. Anderson.

Comment: @snarski: I don't think I have to be that specific about what is a set when writing a comment!!! What is the problem with a "choice"? We make choices all the time. You, for instance, have made the particular choice of making a comment to my comment! :-P

Comment: @AndréCaldas Sorry, I was trying to be funny. What I mean is this: very roughly, you have two types of $E \subset \mathbb{R}$: measurable w.r.t. "Lebesgue" outer measure and not measurable. Thus, when you say "two disjoint sets" it is either trivial or impossible that $m_*(A \cup B) = m_*(A) + m_*(B)$. The pun about "choice" is that I think you need (something equivalent to) the *axiom of choice* to construct these sets. Maybe you know all this? Does this address your question at all?

Comment: @snarski: Sorry for being rude on my last comment. I have the opinion that if you find important state that something depends on a choice, you can simply do that in your answers. I suppose that usually people do not mind using axiom of choice. If you find it really important, you can call attention to the fact in your answers. Otherwise, you'd better comment on virtually every post on this site, noticing people are "making choices" everywhere.

Comment: @snarski: Just to clarify the thing about the "axiom of choice", I believe that without it, or some weaker form, I don't know, there is no set that is not Lebesgue measurable. If there is no such set, then the outer measure is simple the measure it self, and is additive as such. I am not really sure...

Comment: @snarski: I think I understood what you mean. If $E$ is non measurable, by definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), there is a set $A$ such that $\mu^*(A) \neq \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c)$. So, the existence is trivial, as long as you KNOW that there are non measurable sets. I guess a complete argument has to go on the fact that $\mu^*$ is a measure when restricted to measurable sets, but with a choice you can also construct a set that "violates" $\sigma$-aditivity.

Comment: Precisely! Though I think it is possible that $\mu^*(A \cup B) + \mu^*(A) + \mu^*(B)$ for two non-measurable sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @snarski: It surely is. They just have to be "far apart". Like $A \subset [0,1]$ and $B \subset [2,3]$.

Comment: @snarski: I don't really have the time, right now. Why don't you post this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Countably additive holds only If the sets $\{ E_n \} $ are measurable and pairwise disjoint: That is. If $\{ E_n \}_{n\geq 1} $ are measurable, then

$$ \mu^{*} ( \bigcup E_n ) = \sum \mu^*(E_n)  $$

Comment: I am not asking for countably additivity. Does the equality hold for just 2 disjoint sets (whether measurable or not)? If not, what is a possible counterexample? Thank you.

Comment: THe answer is NO. But I cannot think of a counter example right now

Answer (score -1):

For a non-measurable set, the outer measure will necessarily be positive. Therefore it suffices to consider a non-Lebesgue measurable subset $A$ of the circle, and let $B$ be its complement in the circle. Then additivity must fail for this pair of sets for the following example.

Consider a set $A$ of representatives for equivalence classes under the action of rational rotations on the circle (the usual example of a non-measurable set).  Recall that the circle is a countable union of the sets $A_\alpha$ obtained by rotating $A$ by a rational angles $\alpha$.

Let $\epsilon=\mu(A)>0$ where $\mu$ is the outer measure. Let $N=1+\lfloor\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor$. Now take $N$ rational translates of $A$, namely $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_N$. These are all disjoint by construction. If $\mu$ satisifed finite additivity, then the total outer measure would be greater than $1$:
$$
\mu(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_N)=N\cdot\epsilon>1,
$$
yielding the desired contradiction. This shows that the outer measure is not even finitely additive.

Comment: This makes no sense. If the set is not measurable, it has NO Lebesgue measure. Therefore, it cannot have an outer measure greater then something that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, this was written in too much of a hurry.  I clarified what I had in mind above.